# log4net reference error DNX 451 and 5.0

Tags: dnx

I am having trouble implementing log4net using DNX in a class library.  I have the following in my project.json -

```
...
"dependencies": {
        "log4net": "2.0.3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
            }
        }
    }
...
```

When I attempt to use log4net in a class, I get the following error - 
[image]

I do, however, see the reference in the references folder for both DNX 451 and 50.
Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?
Also, if I remove dnxcore50 from my project.json file, it seems to resolve and I can compile the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that log4net has been updated for .Net Core yet, considering beta1 was [released on NuGet November 11, 2014](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta1) and the latest [log4net was released nearly a year before that.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/)

You'll need to either drop log4net or not use ASP.Net Core until they release an update... or [get involved with log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/source-repository.html)!

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to be the answer.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Yeah, I almost have a form response for a lot of these things; since log4net is not on github, though, I had a much harder time to confirm. Good luck with your logging!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) with .NET Core. I've written a sample instruction how to configure this logger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933760/5823245)

Answer (score 0):

As of log4net v2.0.6 they now support NETStandard 1.3 and will work with Core. Although it is missing some features and how you configure it doesn't work quite like the old way, yet.

I wrote up a blog post about how to get it working and configure it: https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/